# How to write a lambda fuction that counts unique count of clients with a condition on other column in a pandas agg function

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, aggregate

I am trying to calculate measures from an initial dataframe with some conditions.
**df** is my initial dataframe.
Here are the measures I need in a new dataframe but I don't know how to keep grouping by columns:

```
df['uniq_view_client'] = df[df['view'] == 1].groupby(['date_diff','platform','l2'])['user_client_id'].nunique()

df['uniq_click_client'] = df[df['click'] == 1].groupby(['date_diff','attributes_platform','l2'])['user_client_id'].nunique()
                
df['view'] = df.groupby(['date_diff','platform','l2'])['view'].sum()

df['click'] = df.groupby(['date_diff','platform','l2'])['click'].sum()
```

I am trying to write it this way but have no idea how to count one column and pass condition to another column in an agg pandas' function

```
agg_mult_df= df.groupby(
     ['date_diff','platform','l2']
 ).agg(
     uniq_view_client=('clint_id','nunique')# pass a lambda function that counts unique number of clients only if views =1,
     uniq_click_client=('clint_id','nunique') #pass a lambda function that counts unique number of clients only if click =1,
     all_view= ('view',   'sum'),
     all_click= ('click',   'sum'),
 ).reset_index()
```

Could anyone help me to figure out the lambda part (I figured that would be the only option), please?

here is the sample
[initial df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyC7B.png)

and the result df

[result df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L1eb.png)

Comment: providing toy data and expected output would lead the community to answer most efficiently

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any solution for the *pandas agg fuction* but did managed to solve it this way :

```
df_test = df.groupby(['date_diff','platform','l2'], as_index=False).apply(lambda x: pd.Series({
        'a_sum'       : x['view'].sum(),
        'a_click'       : x['click'].sum(),
        'client_click'   : x[x['click'] == 1]['client_id'].nunique(),
        'client_view'   : x[x['view'] == 1]['client_id'].nunique()
    
     
  })
).reset_index(drop = True)
```

hope it will be of help to anyone)